# Reporting services Chart line not drawn

Tags: reporting-services

I've build a report for reporting services 2012 R2. This reports looks the following: [image]

When I run the report and tell the parameter to show the results of a single DB the following result is shown:[image]

But when I run the report and tell the parameter to show the results of multiple DBs most of the lines are gone:
[image]

Does anyone know why these lines are disappearing? And how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by declaring the Category field which is normally empty.

[image]